# printf in nodejs execSync gives error - the system cannot find the file specified

Tags: node.js

In node when using ..

```
var child_process = require('child_process')
child_process.execSync("printf 'a'") // works fine
child_process.execSync("printf '<a>'") // throws the system cannot find the file specified
```

I get the error .. the system cannot find the file specified.

Anyone got any ideas how to fix this? I need to use printf. All I want to do is print `<a>`

I am using Windows GIT bash. Node v6.11.3

On the command line .. `printf '<a>'` works fine but `printf \'<a>\'` gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try swapping quote characters:

```
child_process.execSync('printf "<a>"')
```

With the quotes the other way around, the executing shell (which is `cmd.exe` in Windows, I believe) seems to think that you want to redirect a file called "a" into `printf` (like `printf < a`).